# Bootstrap form elements not aligned in horizontal form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I Have a horizontal modal form defined similarly to:

```
<div id="formElements" class="modal-body form-horizontal">
    <div id="catTemplate" class="form-group" style="display:none">
         <div class="controls col-sm-1">
              <a href="javascript:;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></a>
         </div>
         <div class="controls col-sm-7">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Category">
         </div>
         <div class="controls col-xm-3">
              <input class="form-control" type="number" min="0" max="100" style="width:100px;" placeholder="Weight %">
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But my  link floats a little bit above the horizontal line of the other form elements. I attached a screenshot. Is there a way to properly align them?

[image: minus icon not aligned with other form elements]

Comment: If you adjust `line-height` and/or `vertical-align` (of all `inline-block` elements) you can solve your problem.

Comment: You could just add in a top-margin to it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/X9Dzq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use line-height See this [link](http://www.bootply.com/9ANbPsVlzi)

Or you can use [this one](http://www.bootply.com/9ZprI5sn96) too